# I want to retrieve which scheduler is scheduled for a particular day

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
| ID  |                       Name                       | Action | Created By Use Rid | Created Date  |     Days      | Enterprise ID |                Job ID                | Last Updated By Use Rid | Last Updated Date |                                                 Relays                                                 |         Sch Time         | Status |    Timezone    |              Trigger ID              | User ID |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
|  30 | ios                                              |      1 |                  2 | 1559739565592 |               |             2 | ef29baba-534d-4151-80d3-f5a589cf7c22 |                       2 |     1559739565592 |                                                                                                     74 | 2019-06-05T13:04:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 0492dc45-6671-4064-baef-8654761b67f2 |       2 |
|  31 | iot                                              |      0 |                  2 | 1559739617863 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 85e4a611-37dc-45d3-8a2f-243e6d4e0962 |                       2 |     1575869484168 |                                                                                508,509,504,505,506,507 | 2019-12-09T13:50:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | b8a71ee4-94bd-4d2b-b875-7ac1468fad11 |       2 |
|  32 | Daily-8:50 Pm                                    |      1 |                  2 | 1559747777019 |               |             2 | 3f87f532-6289-4016-a6d4-2a76baf4ffb5 |                       2 |     1559749199040 | 45,46,47,48,50,51,52,61,62,63,64,65,302,303,73,74,75,76,77,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,49,66,67,68,304,305 | 2019-06-05T15:41:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 6f1b873b-1e96-47bd-b723-4f50d5534f89 |       2 |
|  33 | TVOffSchedular                                   |      0 |                  2 | 1559933346322 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             4 | 1935f0cf-cdf9-4bdf-895d-9e6dc6c4ddff |                       2 |     1560453392696 |                                                                                                321,325 | 2019-06-13T19:20:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | c6bf383d-7bd7-4364-b077-e8bb3ad857f7 |       2 |
|  34 | TVOnMorning                                      |      1 |                  2 | 1559933392595 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             4 | d90d5c17-46b9-46cc-bb33-07557bf97684 |                       2 |     1559933392595 |                                                                                                321,325 | 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | a131188d-aa7d-4132-995e-035e172566a7 |       2 |
|  35 | MorningOfficeON                                  |      1 |                  2 | 1560004379991 |   1,2,3,4,5,6 |             2 | 8b9163e7-bdea-4ee3-b827-3ab3d4728a0c |                       2 |     1561881126773 |                                                                                                     49 | 2019-06-08T02:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 926e809f-b1fb-4d3c-8da7-b048c0366a3a |       2 |
|  36 | EveningOfficeOFF                                 |      0 |                  2 | 1560005726195 |   1,2,3,4,5,6 |             2 | a7161d66-9ae4-4eb9-bc6e-ded6bd01a766 |                       2 |     1560261033555 |                                                                                                     49 | 2019-06-11T14:00:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | dc45718f-aad4-4eb2-9b94-8a8bc4444385 |       2 |
|  37 | Good night                                       |      1 |                  3 | 1560088585521 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 4e8eedd1-956d-4922-9715-8f9b7bf221cb |                       3 |     1560088585521 |                                                                                                253,363 | 1970-01-01T14:00:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 39a8fb76-06d6-4fdd-8c1f-827c3c1e2c24 |       3 |
|  38 | Good night off                                   |      0 |                  3 | 1560088719173 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | c0a9dfdd-7b1b-4a9e-a9f1-b31d927d995e |                       3 |     1560088719173 |                                                                                                253,363 | 1969-12-31T19:30:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 61cfacdd-f2c8-46c9-b192-228aef33cc59 |       3 |
|  39 | ApplicationON                                    |      1 |                  2 | 1560140790669 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 8f602cc4-8fe7-416a-b563-9b25cd008e5b |                       2 |     1560141163056 |                                                                                   45,46,47,48,50,51,52 | 2019-06-10T04:35:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 5bab6ae0-7c7b-487c-9e72-d6200e0985a2 |       2 |
|  40 | ApplicationMorningOFF                            |      0 |                  2 | 1560140849363 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 7d34c4f1-3638-4355-a14c-622bf733e23e |                       2 |     1560141176600 |                                                                                   45,46,47,48,50,51,52 | 2019-06-10T04:40:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 4cd78892-c2b2-493e-a839-b270eff5aea5 |       2 |
|  41 | DesignNoonOFF                                    |      0 |                  2 | 1560241956756 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 00d3437b-a062-4f32-bb37-200574cac235 |                       2 |     1567674559401 |                                                                                        512,513,514,515 | 2019-09-05T08:15:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | b10d1ded-60a3-4adf-ba6c-743ec3dc4f29 |       2 |
|  42 | DesignNoonON                                     |      1 |                  2 | 1560241995428 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | f3e3807c-7fad-4b08-bb18-439222f8d454 |                       2 |     1567674587127 |                                                                                        512,513,514,515 | 2019-09-05T08:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | c53e9069-164e-430a-89be-913c8127a767 |       2 |
|  43 | blockchain-test                                  |      1 |                  2 | 1560255684868 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 4ac65798-682e-447d-b6cf-813308f05efe |                       2 |     1560257490068 |                                  45,46,47,48,50,51,52,61,62,63,64,65,302,73,74,75,76,53,54,57,58,59,60 | 2019-06-11T12:52:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Calcutta  | 8e7640ea-0223-4a9b-abdc-73c139f8e6fa |       2 |
|  44 | NightLampON                                      |      1 |                  2 | 1560360082007 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             4 | b5aee8d5-8013-4303-88df-6a5e3bc7330e |                       2 |     1560360082007 |                                                                                                    322 | 1970-01-01T17:25:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | d0f3a1b5-93f3-4858-be5f-4837e62dd9bf |       2 |
|  45 | blockchain-off                                   |      1 |                  2 | 1560432958716 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | a3d89bb2-3710-4f8e-9814-1e6942d1a405 |                       2 |     1560432958716 |                                                                                         53,54,57,59,60 | 2019-06-13T13:45:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | a0ccdcb6-a55e-48e2-9391-60d62e10fe4a |       2 |
|  46 | AllLightOffExceptOfficeMaster                    |      0 |                  2 | 1560524588879 |               |             2 | 64939311-522e-4877-b53f-e44ff78200b7 |                       2 |     1560524588879 |                        45,46,47,48,50,51,52,61,62,63,64,302,303,73,74,75,76,77,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60 | 2019-06-14T15:10:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 4a799d93-877c-4d19-b19a-40b6b9767564 |       2 |
|  47 | NightLampOFF                                     |      0 |                  2 | 1560533195543 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             4 | c844b235-3851-4692-ab14-4ee31b5d9404 |                       2 |     1560620178500 |                                                                                                    322 | 2019-06-15T17:40:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | a48c0a99-76cd-4268-b946-8d63408aa234 |       2 |
|  48 | TVON                                             |      1 |                  2 | 1561124197968 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             4 | b0617f91-54b2-48bc-9cf9-2f42fb1526c4 |                       2 |     1571035693157 |                                                                                                321,325 | 2019-06-20T23:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 93d07355-1c95-4faa-ac5c-73b0c68b5323 |       2 |
|  49 | panel light/Inside logo on                       |      1 |                  3 | 1561492261954 |   1,2,3,4,5,6 |             3 | 736609ff-6391-474a-9556-85eff54f2fd8 |                       3 |     1561492261954 |                                                                                        359,360,361,364 | 2019-06-26T14:00:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 84de41a7-a141-49d3-8bf2-8a9a229a8c56 |       3 |
|  50 | Outside Board/panel/focus light ON               |      1 |                  3 | 1562096267147 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 37d4f238-15b3-4a1a-bac1-a050d61792f7 |                       3 |     1572442799792 |                                                                                                    894 | 1970-01-01T13:45:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 3610c4b9-6180-4640-a078-3e310d80b4dd |       3 |
|  51 | Outside Board/Panel/Focus light OFF              |      0 |                  3 | 1562096428205 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 7ef0d450-39f9-4449-beec-c46416c3ebb2 |                       3 |     1572442815806 |                                                                                                    894 | 2019-10-30T16:30:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 8d9fe67d-7d39-4edb-8191-ea8af176b5d7 |       3 |
|  52 | Inside Logo/Panel/Display/Ganpati/Entry light ON |      1 |                  3 | 1562096734383 |   1,2,3,4,5,6 |             3 | 4b6bab36-889a-45ca-969c-a1cecea1f42f |                       3 |     1562096734383 |                                                                                110,111,359,360,361,364 | 2019-07-03T13:30:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | c08cc35a-8e64-4d17-a673-4bfddb2f1c92 |       3 |
|  53 | Inside Logo/Panel/Display/Ganpati/Entrance OFF   |      0 |                  3 | 1562097007454 |   1,2,3,4,5,6 |             3 | 54de42a4-f28e-494a-9ec3-56e22e7956e9 |                       3 |     1562257875176 |                                                                                110,111,359,360,361,364 | 2019-07-03T16:30:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | ffbf0fcd-e6ae-41ba-8873-0d2bbd5d3cd0 |       3 |
|  54 | EveningOfficeON                                  |      1 |                  2 | 1562852792955 |               |             2 | b4c3b59f-8157-4260-b0c0-a76b739e857b |                       2 |     1562852792955 |                                                                             45,46,47,48,61,62,63,64,49 | 2019-07-11T14:01:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 4be1a145-8e21-405e-990d-f85d0c3657bf |       2 |
|  55 | WaterCoolerON                                    |      1 |                  2 | 1564217226090 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 1e9c429f-9a51-4147-815b-efad95330baa |                       2 |     1564217226090 |                                                                                                    489 | 1970-01-01T00:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 4b9413ae-6d13-4117-bc8d-36f02c462b05 |       2 |
|  56 | WaterCoolerOff                                   |      0 |                  2 | 1564217269330 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             2 | 0f2c1112-dd26-43eb-8390-a1bba53789de |                       2 |     1564217269330 |                                                                                                    489 | 1970-01-01T14:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 907e4ee5-367a-4b4b-bc6b-716eeed4c8b8 |       2 |
|  57 | Test 1                                           |      1 |                 28 | 1567236412976 |               |             6 | 2c8276b3-a946-475c-a0e9-7e55569cadae |                      28 |     1567236412976 |                                                                                                    553 | 2019-08-31T07:28:00.000Z |      2 | IST            | dc1fec52-8c98-4832-b01a-a3a91f0b6058 |      28 |
|  58 | Test 3                                           |      1 |                 28 | 1567236499938 |               |             6 | fc820b65-a04c-4ecf-9876-2bd4bb8a8816 |                      28 |     1567237094910 |                                                                                                556,557 | 2019-08-31T07:39:00.000Z |      2 | IST            | ceca92e5-765c-4f54-97ba-77447147276f |      28 |
|  59 | Test 1.1                                         |      1 |                 28 | 1567236608884 |               |             6 | 985e07c0-3a53-4884-a169-19e8a9ae630b |                      28 |     1567236608884 |                                                                                                    553 | 2019-08-31T07:32:00.000Z |      2 | IST            | f1a18b94-ef35-46a7-afbe-c75e743185fe |      28 |
|  60 | Outside C&C Ledlight On                          |      1 |                  3 | 1570365557312 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | ad17d61e-549e-44f1-99db-b50105d069b3 |                       3 |     1574947645835 |                                                                                                    893 | 2019-11-28T12:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 82b0fc02-c98c-4b12-9d8a-3ba2897d1aa7 |       3 |
|  61 | test                                             |      0 |                  2 | 1570532481972 |             1 |             2 | 2d058c32-89f8-4709-ba77-cca2c677334d |                       2 |     1570532481972 |                                                                            524,525,526,527,529,530,531 | 2019-10-08T11:00:00.000Z |      2 | Africa/Lusaka  | 722aece6-39d5-44be-bace-967180cd449f |       2 |
|  62 | Outside C&C Ledlight Off                         |      0 |                  3 | 1570647085459 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 24c4831d-3491-4fa9-a8e2-dab21a94aa93 |                       3 |     1572636959040 |                                                                                                    893 | 2019-10-29T19:00:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 41c21970-faf8-4699-9a97-a49e1b28f3ce |       3 |
|  63 | bedroom allout 1                                 |      1 |                  2 | 1571346220354 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             7 | 9ba4ec5b-c645-4cf6-bede-59fa79073134 |                       2 |     1574015422525 |                                                                                                    662 | 1970-01-01T17:03:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 4aff33ae-6af6-45f3-8407-f67a6f344e4b |       2 |
|  64 | bedroom allout off                               |      0 |                  2 | 1571346263753 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             7 | 8cd3c6ac-0ea6-49b9-af09-10e9dcb3847b |                       2 |     1571346263753 |                                                                                                    662 | 1970-01-01T01:04:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 4ecfcf3f-110c-44b2-9a8d-3f35f1d5a295 |       2 |
|  65 | PIR Enable                                       |      1 |                 25 | 1571649294987 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | c142b8f1-77d6-46a2-8f45-46ad3770a3c4 |                      25 |     1571661763643 |                                                                                                    756 | 2019-10-21T13:00:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 05fc4108-f65a-449f-a211-10e76e080196 |      25 |
|  66 | PIR Disable                                      |      0 |                 25 | 1571649351212 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | 894ef781-cb8f-4139-907f-5d20fc5a0861 |                      25 |     1571649351212 |                                                                                                    756 | 2019-10-21T01:30:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | 0f927aca-f592-44bb-9a7f-67544aa32223 |      25 |
|  67 | testing 22                                       |      1 |                  2 | 1571734869588 |               |             7 | 2fe74039-d25e-4384-bc4a-dd63843de063 |                       2 |     1574015556036 |                                                                                                    639 | 2019-11-20T09:03:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 86cfd858-367a-4a0b-b7eb-35e1096b56f4 |       2 |
|  68 | mobile charger                                   |      0 |                 23 | 1572199190164 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |            11 | 7d536ef8-d24a-4a53-94c0-6c52a441312a |                      23 |     1575485933026 |                                                                                                773,774 | 2019-12-04T21:00:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | fc8b10b3-43a5-497c-86b9-bd55a80cfe4a |      23 |
|  69 | Outside Focus light On                           |      1 |                  3 | 1572637078856 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 9a889394-8102-42a0-836a-43a7ffb5c7bf |                       3 |     1572983697418 |                                                                                                    922 | 2019-11-06T12:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 4747ca5e-736b-4b80-b7a4-9abfe33f0e77 |       3 |
|  70 | Outside Focus light Off                          |      0 |                  3 | 1572637169312 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 1a283075-37e6-4152-a716-a8b63ef62f56 |                       3 |     1572637169312 |                                                                                                    922 | 1969-12-31T18:35:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | fa79f7f6-bde4-4d87-96fd-b570ad47a57c |       3 |
|  71 | Ganpati/Display On                               |      1 |                  3 | 1572637346879 |   2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 6ae8c9ca-e26b-48b8-a3be-ef2d41b0a0d6 |                       3 |     1574943671391 |                                                                                            924,926,894 | 2019-11-28T12:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 0027b2eb-efa2-41ff-ac24-50483eec4632 |       3 |
|  72 | Ganpati/Display Off                              |      0 |                  3 | 1572637442853 |   2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | 0bb73aca-c82d-4459-922b-cb3592783ae9 |                       3 |     1574943713949 |                                                                                            924,926,894 | 2019-11-28T16:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | f8fb596e-dd42-4227-98cb-03a8dcbee9bb |       3 |
|  73 | panel/Logo/Table logo/ Light On                  |      1 |                  3 | 1572638062814 |   2,3,4,5,6,7 |             3 | ab78a500-af55-4c8c-84a8-fdbbe76404f4 |                       3 |     1572638089623 |                                                                                                853,855 | 2019-11-02T12:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 0ef71b02-744c-4755-b7dc-bc51dd727fe9 |       3 |
|  74 | all-out-off                                      |      0 |                 13 | 1572887848318 |     2,3,4,5,6 |            10 | 213f3bab-332a-4992-9d2d-7e38cf48dbfd |                      13 |     1572887848318 |                                                                                                    838 | 2019-11-04T01:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 70938fed-0053-443e-b302-e0f8e25826bb |      13 |
|  75 | mbroom-fan-off                                   |      0 |                 13 | 1572888838651 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |            10 | ae1b74c2-2ad7-4182-9b4d-3f15812edbe8 |                      13 |     1572974583661 |                                                                                                    834 | 2019-11-04T20:45:57.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | e87e19e4-d8ae-45b4-b575-1110d1368648 |      13 |
|  76 | PIR Enable                                       |      1 |                 25 | 1572944519175 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | 6fc17694-4fc5-443e-92ee-ed1132a2ec35 |                      25 |     1572944519175 |                                                                                                    758 | 2019-11-05T12:46:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 46ea68cd-7e11-4003-bdfb-54aab6ba3923 |      25 |
|  77 | PIR Disable                                      |      0 |                 25 | 1572944690715 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | ae7a333c-ff75-4c8b-bcae-92b308180b93 |                      25 |     1573197064859 |                                                                                                    758 | 2019-11-06T00:20:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 6a41e2f1-d029-4d28-9ce7-b2adebb59dab |      25 |
|  78 | test 1                                           |      1 |                  2 | 1573129815561 |               |            16 | ab60b929-48ed-43ab-9a89-45bfc0a10ee3 |                       2 |     1573129815561 |                                                                                                   1030 | 2019-11-07T12:32:13.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 80c7d1b2-68b4-425e-91b4-d82544d66dfc |       2 |
|  79 | pir en test                                      |      1 |                 25 | 1573196361376 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | a206b1f6-f1e8-4c12-a97f-b7d217fd344a |                      25 |     1573196739778 |                                                                                                    758 | 2019-11-08T07:08:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | dc23b8ee-2da0-42a3-a6d0-35a328035e12 |      25 |
|  80 | pir dbtest                                       |      0 |                 25 | 1573196399643 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             9 | 5d133d17-8495-4e34-aa6c-ea13344ddfdc |                      25 |     1573196765147 |                                                                                                    758 | 2019-11-08T07:09:00.000Z |      2 | Asia/Kolkata   | b431f3fc-f541-4912-b698-83f574c1c811 |      25 |
|  81 | living-off                                       |      0 |                 13 | 1573408027950 |               |            10 | cac70a87-98b3-405f-a6da-2ac6f1c3a344 |                      13 |     1573408137563 |                                                                                                    813 | 2019-11-10T20:30:56.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 7b91172a-da7b-4f94-bf92-7915b51fce98 |      13 |
|  82 | ro on                                            |      1 |                  2 | 1573416862256 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             7 | 22e7e1ab-d2f3-483e-bcc5-3aa595feedb8 |                       2 |     1573416862256 |                                                                                                    672 | 1970-01-01T00:08:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 747f6396-77b7-4bab-93a2-6c6715b3e87f |       2 |
|  83 | RO off                                           |      0 |                  2 | 1573473725301 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             7 | eed1acbd-0850-4dc1-ad65-2528eb630389 |                       2 |     1573473725301 |                                                                                                    672 | 1969-12-31T19:01:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Calcutta  | 89a511e2-52f6-45f3-9257-78b7f9f41bc2 |       2 |
|  84 | Test                                             |      1 |                 42 | 1573738374195 |               |            17 | fca106ba-af83-4bae-8855-aa4d9edd4484 |                      42 |     1573738590203 |                                                                                    1133,1134,1135,1136 | 2019-11-14T13:38:29.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | f668dc34-db5b-4f34-a5a1-ee7649bc093d |      42 |
|  85 | entrance                                         |      0 |                 42 | 1573738946510 |               |            17 | ce332a00-b3ca-45cc-9c1d-c3ead60845fd |                      42 |     1573738946510 |                                                                                                   1133 | 2019-11-14T13:47:25.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | c7b912db-096a-4836-8b1d-0b52197922c5 |      42 |
|  86 | ronak bedroom charger                            |      1 |                 15 | 1573827203905 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |            15 | a31cc0a3-cfcd-4a57-8a72-f292893c4de9 |                      15 |     1574274253149 |                                                                                                   1103 | 2019-11-14T23:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 91a3e0c7-f750-42ca-84e0-af4bbb7ef839 |      15 |
|  87 | ronak bedroom plug off                           |      0 |                 15 | 1573827259380 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |            15 | 7f9e1f0f-e126-4bdd-acce-967bfb785c25 |                      15 |     1574274268343 |                                                                                                   1103 | 2019-11-15T01:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | dc3b7742-711c-46c5-9395-38c9568d32dc |      15 |
|  88 | fan off                                          |      0 |                 15 | 1573845123332 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |            15 | d5c68535-499a-436d-844f-8d0d7140d2da |                      15 |     1573845123332 |                                                                                                   1096 | 2019-11-15T20:32:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | a014d04c-48dc-4ec4-a56f-90383387c241 |      15 |
|  89 | master beroom all out on                         |      1 |                 20 | 1574014827858 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             8 | f25ae2d2-9414-418a-878b-1545a956d5fe |                      20 |     1574014827858 |                                                                                                    700 | 2019-11-17T17:00:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | 3cded4f6-9740-43fa-b921-b5b9deb5bdb5 |      20 |
|  90 | master bedroom plug 4                            |      0 |                 20 | 1574015013470 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |             8 | 1daabfe0-ccaa-4821-8658-c556541771a4 |                      20 |     1574042395372 |                                                                                                    700 | 2019-11-18T00:30:00.000Z |      0 | Asia/Kolkata   | fa0aad18-fe38-4e2f-8753-caef702ab74c |      20 |
|  91 | light on                                         |      0 |                 22 |                       
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

In the below data the sch time needs to be compared with Days ie when the Days column is null then sch Time should be the output and when it is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 then case when 1 then return sunday,  case when 2 then return monday,case when 3 then return tues, case when 4 then return wed, case when 5 then return thur, case when 6 then return fri, case when 7 then return sat. should be the output  The data should be time and date sorted decreasing

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, see MySQL's date functions; it's well aware of the index values for days of the week.

Comment: no i tried using date function but this is not the answer i am looking for..i am looking for each id when is the scheduler scheduled. if null is there in days column then output should be sch Time or else if it is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 then case when 1 then return sunday, case when 2 then return monday,case when 3 then return tues, case when 4 then return wed, case when 5 then return thur, case when 6 then return fri, case when 7 then return sat. should be the output The data should be time and date sorted decreasing

Comment: @AjeetVerma okay..!how can this problem be solved?

Comment: A clue:  See `FIND_IN_SET(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()), DAYS)`

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query and put your table name at the place **Your_table**.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.dates ADD update_stat BIT DEFAULT(0) --You can add this in current table or temp table 

WHILE EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 update_stat
        FROM Your_Table
        WHERE update_stat = 0
        ORDER BY Id
        )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @days VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @datepart VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Id INT

    SET @datepart = DATEPART(dw, getdate())
    SET @days = (
            SELECT TOP 1 days
            FROM dbo.dates
            WHERE days IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY ID
            )
    SET @ID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 ID
            FROM dbo.dates
            WHERE days IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY ID
            )

    IF CHARINDEX(@datepart, @days) > 0
BEGIN
        UPDATE Your_Table
        SET update_stat = 1
        WHERE id = @Id
END

SELECT

SELECT DATEPART(d, getdate()) AS DaysNo
    ,CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'SUNDAY'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'MONDAY'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'TUESDAY'
        WHEN 4
            THEN 'WEDNESDAY'
        WHEN 5
            THEN 'THURSDAY'
        WHEN 6
            THEN 'FRIDAY'
        WHEN 7
            THEN 'SATURDAY'
        END AS DaysName
    ,*
FROM Your_Table
WHERE update_stat = 1
```

You can insert the new column the **update_stat** either in the same table or you can insert all the existing table data into **temp table** and then add a **update_stat** column using below query and rest are same start from **WHILE** Loop.

```
SELECT * INTO ##tempTable
FROM Your_Table
ALTER TABLE dbo.dates ADD update_stat BIT DEFAULT(0)---rest are same..
```